# How to find out where the search keyword is found in full-text search

Tags: sql-server-2008, full-text-search

Consider this

```
SELECT  * 
FROM Publication a          
INNER JOIN  CONTAINSTABLE(Publication, (Title, Keywords), 
@TitlePartial)TitleSearchPartial ON  a.Id = TitleSearchPartial.[Key]
```

I am searching in (`Title` and `Keyword`) columns of the `Publication` table .
The search key word can be found anywhere in 'Title' or 'Keyword'
How to find which column the search keyword has been found in? Is there a out-of-box way to do this?

Any ideas...

Answer (score 0):

Can you try something like this:

```
SELECT *,
    CASE
        WHEN b.[Key] IS NOT NULL THEN 'Title'
        WHEN c.[Key] IS NOT NULL THEN 'Keywords'
        END AS MatchColumn
FROM Publication a
    LEFT JOIN CONTAINSTABLE(Publication, Title, @TitlePartial) b
        ON a.Id = b.[Key]
    LEFT JOIN CONTAINSTABLE(Publication, Keywords, @TitlePartial) c
        ON a.Id = c.[Key]
WHERE (b.[Key] IS NOT NULL
        OR c.[Key] IS NOT NULL)
```

You might have to add another case for matching both columns.  Also, I have no way to test this right now, unfortunately.